# PrintWindow works in standalone application and does partially work in NPAPI plugin

Tags: windows, google-chrome, plugins, npapi, screen-capture

I have a code, which captures a given window by PrintWindow function. Specifically I do capture web-pages in a browser. This code is tested in a standalone Windows application, and it works ok. The same code is incorporated into NPAPI plugin and loaded into Google Chrome. There problems happen. If Chrome has only one tab, the code works OK. If Chrome has 2 tabs, the code returns black box of expected size. I tested the standalone application and the plugin at the same moment, on the same window handle (Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND). Application does ALWAYS work, the plugin does ALWAYS fail if multiple tabs are open in the browser.

I'd really appreciate, if someone give a clue how to fix this.

Thanks in advance.

*NB. Other methods of capturing windows are inapplicable due to even greater shortcomings for my usecase.*

Answer (score 0):

I bet you're running into sandboxing issues.

Your app is likely running at the "normal" integrity level, so it has no problem posting the `WM_PRINT` or `WM_PRINTCLIENT` message to the Chrome process.  (`PrintWindow` uses these messages under the covers.)

When you're a plugin in Chrome, I believe your code runs as a "low" integrity process (which reduces the chances of things like shatter attacks).  Thus it doesn't surprise me that sending the message to a window in another process fails.

Unfortunately, that doesn't explain why it works when Chrome has only one tab. Are you finding the same instance of `Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND` in both the app and the plugin in the case where you have multiple tabs open?  In general, there's one of these windows per tab.  How are you finding the window?

Comment: I have not thus far been enable to determine for sure if Chrome starts plugins in low integrity mode or not; I have seen a lot of rumors floating around, but can not find any concrete place where it is stated nor have I had any of the problems in a chrome plugin that I might normally associate with low integrity.

Comment: I test the code upon the same window (the handles of all Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND are logged, so I just choose one and capture it by the plugin and by the application). Unfortunately I can't guarantee that the plugin is loaded into the same process, as the captured tab. As you know Chrome creates a lot of processes - one from the start and at least 2 for every tab, but the plugin is loaded only once (it is not injected into a page but sits in its own background page). But please note that standalone app also is another process, and it works. So it's still a mystery for me.

Comment: @Taxilian: This document discusses the use of the low-integrity bit in the sandboxing model used by Chrome:  http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/sandbox

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy, this is not related to integrity levels, because it occures under Windows XP as well, where there is no integrity levels. Perhaps, job restrictions may be a next candidate to suspect, but still it's not clear why external process, which is out of the scope of Chrome jobs, can handle the operation. Anyway, I moved all capturing functionality from the plugin into external application.