# Does Google Chrome Repaint a Unfocused tab?

Tags: google-chrome, rendering

I was having a discussion with my colleague on repainting of unfocused tabs on Google Chrome. It was undecided whether Chrome repainted pages that weren't focused and hidden, and whether this is different for different kinds of scenarios (static pages, changing css, gif animations, flash)? And how is this different from normal apps hidden behind other windows?

Comment: What do you mean with "hidden"? If you open several Chrome windows only one will sit at the top, and the others will be "hidden" under the first. With such configuration I can confirm that Chrome renders changes for every dynamic content of the "hidden" windows, because I wrote software which opened several browser windows and captured them in action. I think tabs operate in similar way.

Comment: @Stan Yes That is what I mean by hidden (for example, tabs), could you give an more detailed answer on your software?

Comment: @TiansHUo I would tend to say that hidden tabs do not get repainted untill they are focused because the requestAnimationFrame method is never called in an unfocused tab. On the contrary, it does in an hidden window.

Comment: I wrote a server for Remote Brower Control, so to speak. It started Chrome instances on demand (for each new user connected), and captured each instance, and controlled it by remote user commands. Each instance was intentionally moved to a separate window for proper capture, so I can't tell if the repaint would break if pages were left in tabs. By the way, Chrome extenions API does not even have an event for tab deactivation, so it's a little bit tricky to deactivate extension scripts in background, though it's of course possible if someone decide to write a workaround intentionally.

Comment: I just checked my old test capturing application, and it seems that Chrome indeed stops rendering hidden **tabs**, producing black boxes. I suspect this is exactly the matter why I got black boxes in those past times, when I even posted a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8539102/printwindow-works-in-standalone-application-and-does-partially-work-in-npapi-plu).